# Scala library that inputs SQL and outputs collections, but for SPARQL / Gremlin?

Tags: scala, sparql, graph-databases, gremlin, gremlin-server

In Scala, we have libraries that allow you to write SQL and get back immutable collections. For example, [Doobie](https://tpolecat.github.io/doobie/) and [ScalikeJDBC](http://scalikejdbc.org/). Is there anything like that, but for [SPARQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPARQL) or [Apache TinkerPop Gremlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gremlin_(programming_language))? I have a Java/Scala based [Graph Database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database) instead of a relational database.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understood the question. What exactly are you looking for? Just a SPARQL API for Java? Like Jena or RDF4J? Or what means *"immutable collections"* as output? The result of a SPARQL SELECT query is usually a resultset

Comment: This probably going to be closed since questions asking for tool/resource recommendations are considered off-topic on StackOverflow. Like AKSW said though, there's two major Java APIs for SPARQL querying available, Jena and RDF4J. I know of at least one project that uses RDF4J successfully in a Scala environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two well maintained Scala libraries:

- [Gremlin-Scala](https://github.com/mpollmeier/gremlin-scala) for Apache Tinkerpop 3
- [`banana-rdf`](https://github.com/banana-rdf/banana-rdf) for RDF, SPARQL, and Linked Data technologies in Scala

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correct than you can use Apache Jena for the same. Please look at the link:

https://jena.apache.org/documentation/rdfconnection/

Answer (score -1):

I think I found something, but it is for Python:
https://github.com/RDFLib/sparqlwrapper

I need something for Scala or Java 8+.

Comment: I think it's better to add this to your question